# How to set condition inside Jquery .Live () function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am calling `live('click')` function in which i call ajax method and do some server side functionality.
But before ajax call i need  to `check` for `valid data`.
Am bit confused how to call it

```
 // Depend on this condition i have to start process my ajax function.
    function validData()
    {
     if ($('.edt').val() == "")
        {

            return false;
        }

        var maxtxtvalue = $('edt3').val();
        var mintxtvalue = $('edt4').val();

       // alert(maxtxtvalue > mintxtvalue);
        if(parseInt(maxtxtvalue) > parseInt(mintxtvalue))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {   
            $('input:text[id$="txtmaxctc"]').val('');
            $('input:text[id$="txtminctc"]').val('');
            alert("Max ctc must be greater then Min ctc.");
            return false;  
        }
    }

 $("img[class^='sav_']").live('click', function (event) {
    if( return false )
    {

    }
    else{
        //start process
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_function/updatefn.asmx/upajx",
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + dataString + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);

                    }   });
    }
   });
```

Comment: You are aware that there is a typo on line 2? `fucntion`.

Comment: @BramVanroy: you mean to say `.edt` ??. its my class name

Comment: You have written `fucntion` instead of `function` on line 2.

Comment: @BramVanroy: thanks will update it now

Comment: Don't use live() use on() as of jQuery 1.7 live() is deprecated.

Comment: @Precastic: useing  `.on()` gives error `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`  at `$("img[class^='sav_']").on("click", function (event) {`

Comment: Then you are probably using a version of jQuery < 1.7. It would probably be worth upgrading if you are at the beginning of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Depend on this condition i have to start process my ajax function.

can't you do like this..

```
    function validData()
    {
     if ($('.edt').val() == "")
        {

            return false;
        }

        var maxtxtvalue = $('edt3').val();
        var mintxtvalue = $('edt4').val();

       // alert(maxtxtvalue > mintxtvalue);
        if(parseInt(maxtxtvalue) > parseInt(mintxtvalue))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {   
            $('input:text[id$="txtmaxctc"]').val('');
            $('input:text[id$="txtminctc"]').val('');
            alert("Max ctc must be greater then Min ctc.");
            return false;  
        }
    }

 $("img[class^='sav_']").live('click', function (event) {
    if(validData() )
    {

    }
    else{
        //start process
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_function/updatefn.asmx/upajx",
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + dataString + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);

                    }   });
    }
   });
```

Comment: thanks that was so simple, now am thinking why i didnt tried it myself